# Getting React-Viro Build working on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native development.

I have been trying to get a React-Viro project to successfully build onto my mobile S8 android device and have been struggling a lot. I am in a windows 10 environment using git-bash.

**First Approach**
I have been following the steps on the react-viro quickstart website.

1) `react-native init ProjectAR --version0.57.7`

2) `cd ViroSample`

3) `npm install -S -E react-viro`

4) copy the files from node_modules\react-viro\bin\files\javascript* to the root

5) In App.js assign API Key.

6) In index.android.js change to the name of my project
`AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProjectAR', () => App);`

When I run `react-native run-android` I get the error on my phone

> Unable to resolve module 'react-native/Libraries/DeprecatedPropTypes/DeprecatedStyleSheetPropType from ...\ProjectAR\node_modules\react-viro\components\ViroImage.js
>
> Module 'react-native/Libraries/DeprecatedPropTypes/DeprecatedStyleSheetPropType' does not exist in the current Haste module map

**Second Approach**
1) `npm install -g react-viro-cli`

2) `react-viro init NewArProject`

3) `cd NewArProject`

4) `./setup-ide.sh android`

5) In App.js assign API Key.

When I run `react-native run-android` I get the error in my terminal

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are: 'installArDebug', 'installGvrDebug', 'installOvrDebug'.

I go into my android directory and do
`./gradlew app:installArDebug`

But I get an error

> Execution failed for task ':app:generateArDebugBuildConfig'.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-native run-android --variant=gvrDebug` instead.